# FindControl() Keeps Returning Null!

Tags: asp.net, controls

I realise there are many posts on the web about this already but I cant seem to find any for my particular problem!

I have a dynamic table that is populated using a repeater.

the code is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPending" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblPending" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <th>Fax Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox ID="a" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" 
                onChange="__doPostBack($(this).attr('name'),$(this).parent().attr('id'));" 
                Text='<%# Eval("_companyName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>                          
            <td runat="server">                           
                <asp:TextBox ID="b" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" 
                onChange="__doPostBack($(this).attr('name'),$(this).parent().attr('id'));" 
                Text='<%# Eval("_telephone")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>                          
            <td runat="server">                           
                <asp:TextBox ID="c" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" 
                onChange="__doPostBack($(this).attr('name'),$(this).parent().attr('id'));" 
                Text='<%# Eval("_faxNo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>                
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody> </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Once this table has been populated with data from a datasource, a jquery script iterates through every table cell and edits the id's accordingly. cell_0_0, cell_0_1, cell_0_2 etc.

Now When the text on these text areas change, a postback is initiated, with the __EVENTTARGET being the textarea ID, and the __EVENTARGUMENT being the table cell (parent) ID.

These get sent to the server-side no problem. The issue I am having is GETTING THE TEXT inside the text area...

I have tried adding controls using FindControl("cell_0_0"); Which returns null. Then i found out the FindControl() function IS NOT recursive, so i copied a recursive function off the net... and it Still Fails!

Basically ALL i need to do is GET the value (either innerText or InnerHTML). Ive tried using Control, HtmlControl, HtmlTableRow, and HtmlTextArea.

I just cant seem to get the value. Ive tried recursing throught i a noted earlier, but the controls arent even registered. Im confused.

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 4):

Well this is a usually issue, because of the timing of the creations of the controls, and when you create control inside a repeater the timing is even more complex because repeater must first full bind, and then search for the controls.

In my programs to avoid all that I just get the posted value from the Form and I actually not first search to find the control. So just get your posted values from the Request.Form and move on.

```
Request.Form
```

All the post data lives on Request.Form, so you can simple get the one you need, or find the one you need. Just a note, to get a value using the Form use the UniqueID, and not the ClientID. Even better get the value from your custom name ids.